# How do I get Heroku to log from a worker process?

Tags: ruby, logging, heroku, worker

I'm trying to get Heroku to run a simple Ruby process and write to Logplex.

My Procfile:

```
worker: ruby test_app.rb
```

test_app.rb:

```
puts 'LOGGGGG!'
raise 'we have a problem'
sleep(10)
```

When I run heroku local, I get the expected output:

```
forego  | starting worker.1 on port 5000
worker.1 | test_app.rb:10:in `<main>': we have a problem (RuntimeError)
worker.1 | LOGGGGG!
```

But when I add, commit and push to Heroku as normal I get nothing in the logs (`heroku logs`) - only this:

```
2015-11-27T17:55:39.671609+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-27T17:55:39.671620+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
```

What can I possibly be doing wrong? I'm at a loss...
Thanks,
Louise

EDIT: my push output looks like this:

```
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 286 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.2
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Using minitest 5.8.3
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using amq-protocol 2.0.0
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.0
remote:        Using connection_pool 2.2.0
remote:        Using netrc 0.7.9
remote:        Using redis 3.2.2
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using bunny 2.2.1
remote:        Using rest_client 1.8.3
remote:        Using sidekiq 4.0.1
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.5
remote:        Bundle complete! 7 Gemfile dependencies, 15 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (0.26s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> worker
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 18.1MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v19
remote:        https://application-name.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To git@heroku.com:application-name.git
   75d764d..a7d6bdb  master -> master
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you scale up a worker process after you've done your deployment?

`heroku ps:scale worker=1` would start a worker process. Doing this you'll get...

```
2015-11-27T18:09:16.366187+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-27T18:09:16.366197+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-27T18:10:14.409542+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1, worker=1 by me@me.com
2015-11-27T18:10:16.657359+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `ruby test_app.rb`
2015-11-27T18:10:17.365815+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-27T18:10:18.668842+00:00 app[worker.1]: test_app.rb:3:in `<main>': we have a problem (RuntimeError)
2015-11-27T18:10:18.669815+00:00 app[worker.1]: LOGGGGG!
2015-11-27T18:10:19.493559+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Heroku will only start the `web` process by default, you need to scale up the `worker` process.